# How to recreate Zoom-In effect for launching apps on iOS 7 Springboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I currently have a Parent view controller, with a circle subview called itemView in the center.

When I long press, I need to add a child view controller, and have that childVC's animation mimmic that off the springboard icon launch animation.

This is my code currently, which creates a new VC with a view set in the items center than scales it to the screen. But how can I get the actually item to become the VC & scale up into the screen.

Can anyone help me recreate the springboard effect?

Thanks in advance.

```
self.ViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone_Storyboard"
                                                              bundle:nil]     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];

        [self addChildViewController:self.ViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.ViewController.view];

        self.ViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);

        CGPoint originalCenter = self.ViewController.view.center;

        self.ViewController.view.center = itemView.center;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             // Grow!
                             self.ViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                             self.ViewController.view.center = originalCenter;

                             itemView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
```